# Summing up decimals returned within task

Tags: vb.net, task, wait

I'm trying to run through a list of 1-X items and process them in Tasks in order to speed up completion of processing (they make web requests that can sometimes take a short while to finish).  I'm trying to sum up a decimal that is returned when the processing is finished without looping through the list a second time.  As it is right now, the sum is overwritten by each task instead of being added to.

I can insert a short pause before adding the decimal to the sum and this seems to work fine, but I'm sure there is a better solution out there.

I've seen mentions of SyncLock but I can't use it on a Decimal.

Here is some code I wrote for testing. The .Process method just waits a random number of seconds and sets the .Value property to a random decimal.

Any suggestions for improvement and calculating the sum in a proper way?

```
    Try
        Dim lstItem As List(Of clsItem) = GetList()
        Dim lstViewItem As New List(Of ListViewItem)
        Dim lstTasks As New List(Of Task)()
        Dim decTotal As Decimal = 0.0
        For i As Int32 = 0 To lstItem.Count - 1
            Dim j As Int32 = i
            Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                         lstViewItem.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {j, lstItem(j).Process()}))
                                         'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(j * 1000)
                                         decTotal += lstItem(j).Value
                                     End Sub)
            lstTasks.Add(t)
        Next
        Task.WaitAll(lstTasks.ToArray())
        lstView.Items.AddRange(lstViewItem.ToArray())
        lstView.Items.Add("")
        lstView.Items.Add(decTotal)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: First question, what is the purpose of `j`?  Is there a reason why you're not just using `i` because of code elsewhere? Also what happens if you use `Static decTotal As Decimal = 0.0`?

Comment: @PaulIshak, Yes, it most certainly is. [Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx)

Comment: @BrandonB I have j in there because at one point I was getting the warning "Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable."  And I get the same result when I use Static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `SyncLock` to resolve your issue. SyncLock can only be used on reference types. All that's needed is to create a new object that is within the scope of the current instance and then let `SyncLock` lock on that object.

Here's a short little console application that utilizes `SyncLock`. I significantly simplified what you had. I didn't really feel like making listViews and such, and rather than returning a random decimal it just returns 1 so that the results should be the number of loop iterations.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim lstTasks As New List(Of Task)()
        Dim SyncLockedTotal As Decimal = 0D
        Dim decTotal As Decimal = 0D
        Dim sLock As New Object
        For i As Int32 = 1I To 1000I
            Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                         Dim tempDecimal As Decimal = clsItem.Process()
                                         decTotal += tempDecimal
                                         SyncLock sLock
                                             SyncLockedTotal += tempDecimal
                                         End SyncLock
                                     End Sub)
            lstTasks.Add(t)
        Next
        Task.WaitAll(lstTasks.ToArray())
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value for decTotal: {0}", decTotal.ToString))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value for SyncLockedTotal: {0}", SyncLockedTotal.ToString))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Structure clsItem
    Public Shared Function Process() As Decimal
        Dim rnd As New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(10I))
        Return 1D
    End Function
End Structure
```

**NOTE: Your application settings must target .NET 4.5 in order to use `Task.Run()`, if you are targetting .NET 4 you will have to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. If you are targeting .NET 3.5 or lower, this won't work for you because you won't have the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace available.**